# Photoshop script is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

This script changes the color of the text in the active layer to black, exports it as a PNG file with the specified name, then it changes the color of the text in the active layer to white, and exports it again as a PNG file with the specified name, and it repeats the same process with different colors (pink, blue, green, red) and save them as PNG files with different names.

The Black, Blue, Green and Red are exported correctly. However white (which comes right after black) is exported as light blue and the pink file (which comes after white) is exported as the same color of the blue file.

```
var textColor = new SolidColor();
textColor.rgb.hexValue = “000000”;
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = textColor;

var textLayerName = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name;

var newName = prompt(“Enter a new name for the export”, “black_” + textLayerName);

var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
exportOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
exportOptions.quality = 100;
var file = new File("black " + newName + “.png”);
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

var textColor = new SolidColor();
textColor.rgb.hexValue = “FFFFFF”;
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = textColor;

var file2 = new File("white " + newName + “.png”);
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file2, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

var textColor = new SolidColor();
textColor.rgb.hexValue = “fc82d8”;
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = textColor;

var file3 = new File("pink " + newName + “.png”);
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file3, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

var textColor = new SolidColor();
textColor.rgb.hexValue = “63a8e7”;
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = textColor;

var file4 = new File("blue " + newName + “.png”);
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file4, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

var textColor = new SolidColor();
textColor.rgb.hexValue = “0c6a27”;
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = textColor;

var file5 = new File("green " + newName + “.png”);
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file5, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

var textColor = new SolidColor();
textColor.rgb.hexValue = " a80000";
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = textColor;

var file6 = new File("red " + newName + “.png”);
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file6, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);
```

Comment: Check your quotes - it should be ", not “ nor ”. Also, this: `" a80000"` should be this: `"a80000"` (no space). Your script works fine, otherwise, though I'd consider saving the images to Desktop, instead of where the executable is located.

Comment: Yeah my error on the "a80000". However, as I've mentioned, for some reason it mistekenly exports the file that should be white as the color light blue and the file that should be pink as the color blue instead of their respective colors

Comment: No error on my end - the colors are exported properly (tested on an ancient CS5 version). What happens if you replace these `“` with a regular quote symbol (the one you're using for colour names)?

Comment: SOLVED! 
Apparently if i add write "FFFFFF" it exports it wrong. But if i write " FFFFFF" it will export it white as it should. Same thing goes for red and pink, not for blue or green or black.

Comment: Do you know how could i export the file not in a .zip folder but in a normal folder called "*number that goes up every output* + *name inputed in the prompt*"?

Comment: Can you create a new question, and post what the expected outcome would be?

Comment: Sure. Do I need to name the new question as something particular so you can find it or not. Moreover, What does "post what the expected outcome would be" mean, should I post the thing I'd like it to do (so export the files in a normal folder called "*number that goes up every output* + *name inputed in the prompt*" instead of the .zip folder it creates)?

Comment: Just name in in a way which would describe the problem. And by expected outcome, I mean something like this: *My current setup is outputting <whatever_the_setup_is_outputting>, and I would like it to output <specific_example_of_what_you_would_like>*

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75268049/photoshop-script-to-export-files-in-a-normal-folder-with-an-arbitrarian-name-in